# Java Regex: find single quoted text with escapes

Tags: java, regex, single-quotes

This method should return all occurrences of single-quoted strings. However, an escaped single quote (`\’`) should be treated as a regular single-quote character (just like an escaped double-quote in Java). Example:  “`This ’isn\’t’ easy’`” the method should return the single string `“isn’t`”.
My code:

```
public static List<String> findSingleQuotedTextWithEscapes(String input) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("(?:\\w|'[^']*')+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher (input);
        ArrayList ans = new ArrayList();
        while (matcher.find ()){
            ans.add (matcher.group ().replace ("'",""));
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Input: `"more'test'"` Expected: `[test]` Actual: `[more,test]`
I seem to have a problem with catching just the ' character and I'm tokenizing everything, please help.
Adding tester:

```
void fillSingleQuotedTestInputs(List<String> inputs, List<List<String>> expect) {
        inputs.add("'test'"); expect.add(Arrays.asList("test"));
        inputs.add("more'test'"); expect.add(Arrays.asList("test"));
        inputs.add("'test'more"); expect.add(Arrays.asList("test"));
        inputs.add("\\'no'yes'"); expect.add(Arrays.asList("yes"));
        inputs.add("a 'one' and 'two' and 'three'..."); expect.add(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
        inputs.add("nothing at all"); expect.add(Arrays.<String>asList());
        inputs.add("''"); expect.add(Arrays.asList(""));
        inputs.add("''test"); expect.add(Arrays.asList(""));
        inputs.add("test''"); expect.add(Arrays.asList(""));
        inputs.add("te''st"); expect.add(Arrays.asList(""));
        inputs.add("'This is not wrong' and 'this isn\\'t either'"); expect.add(Arrays.asList("This is not wrong", "this isn't either"));
        inputs.add("'tw\\'o repl\\'acements' in 't\\'wo stri\\'ngs'."); expect.add(Arrays.asList("tw'o repl'acements", "t'wo stri'ngs"));
        inputs.add("'\\''"); expect.add(Arrays.asList("'"));
        inputs.add("'''"); expect.add(Arrays.asList(""));
        inputs.add("'test1'\n'test2'"); expect.add(Arrays.asList("test1", "test2"));
        inputs.add("''''"); expect.add(Arrays.asList("", "")); // This one is hard. Hint: \G
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindSingleQuotedTextWithEscapes() {
        ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<List<String>> expect = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        fillSingleQuotedTestInputs(inputs, expect);

        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i) {
            List<String> output = RegexpPractice.findSingleQuotedTextWithEscapes(inputs.get(i));
            assertEquals(String.format("Test %d failed: Search <<%s>>", i, inputs.get(i)), expect.get(i), output);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Anything wrong with `\w+\\’\w+`?

Comment: that won't catch anything that has the ' in the middle of the word

Comment: I see, so you need some lookarounds. `(?<=’)\w+(?:\\’\w+)*(?=’)` https://regex101.com/r/dNQoCF/1

Comment: How would I do this without lookarounds ?

Comment: Why? Java supports lookarounds so use lookarounds.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `(?<!\\)'(.*?)(?<!\\)'` will meet all of your needs. It uses a negative lookbehind to assert that, when matching `'`, there isn't a `\` behind it. This passes all of the test cases shown in your code.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NU0Hy3/1)

If you want to do it without lookarounds, you can use `(?:[^'\n\r]*?'()'|[^\\]'(.*?[^\\])')`. Note that this performs more slowly than the first regex shown.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NU0Hy3/2)

Comment: Thank you, though it did need a bit of modification to the ```add```
So I changed the add to: ```ans.add (matcher.group ().replaceAll ("'","").replace ("\\","'"));```

Comment: If the question was on the double quotes, how would that change the answer?

Comment: How can I do that without lookarounds?

Comment: @Yuki1112 answer updated for regex w/o lookarounds. Note that it performs more slowly than the original; it hasn't been tested as vigorously but matches all your test cases.

Comment: thank you, however for some reason it adds the first character of the string to the answer, why is that?

Comment: That's one of the caveats of not using lookarounds. Note that an extra character is added to the *match*, but the *capture group* is exactly the same - I think that's what you'll want to be using.

Comment: @Rika change all of the `'` to `"` and that should be enough - neither of them have special meaning in regex or need to be escaped. You'd likely have to put together new test cases, though!

Comment: Thank you, managed to fix it, however I still can't fix the case of having a \ in middle of a quote. Example: Input: fdsaf'te\st'fdsafdsa Expected: te\st Actual: te'st

Comment: That's an issue with your replacement, then - this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NU0Hy3/3) shows that the regex is returning the correct string.

Answer (score 0):

Taking care of backslashes eating the next char or else non-apostrophes:

```
String s = "1.'2\'3\\'xx'x'";
//            [^^^^^^]  [^]

List<String> findQuotedText(Strings) {
    Pattern quotedPattern = Pattern.compile("'((\\\\.|[^\\\\']+)*)'");
    //                                        |    |    |        |
    //                                apostrophe   |    |       apostrophe
    //                                 backslash+any or non-apostrophes
    Matcher m = quotedPattern.matcher(s);
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        results.add(m.group(1));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Result:

```
2'3\
```

Comment: it works on the start of the phrase but doesn't continue until the end of the word, please note also that this is a list.
Example: input: fdsaf'te\'st'fdsafdsa . expected: te'st Actual: te\

Comment: Corrected; the alternative to `\.` had to include not-backslash.